# url image from Database [Symfony2]

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to charge some images from the database  using asset(), but it shows in the url : /Symfony/web/bundles/crs/images/item.url

```
<img src='{{ asset("bundles/crs/images/{{item.url}}")}}' />
```

how can i solve this? Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<img src='{{ asset("bundles/crs/images/"~ item.url)}}' />`